# In Symfony2 , How do you mock a Console Component which is consuming another ConsoleComponent

Tags: php, unit-testing, symfony, mocking

I'm writing a console component using Symfony2 libraries that consumes another application that's also written with symfony2 console components.

I want to mock the other applications console component, how do I go about achieving this? The application I'm building is simply consuming an existing command from another application:

Basically, how do you write a unit test for the code below:

```
protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
{
    $command = $this->getApplication()->find('demo:greet');

    $arguments = array(
        'command' => 'demo:greet',
        'name'    => 'Fabien',
        '--yell'  => true,
    );

    $input = new ArrayInput($arguments);
    $returnCode = $command->run($input, $output);

    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another application or the same application?

```
$commandMock = $this->getMock('Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command');
$commandMock->expects($this->once())->method('run')->with(...)->will($this->returnValue(1));

$applicationMock = $this->getMockBuilder('Symfony\Component\Console\Application')
    ->disableConstructor()->getMock();
$applicationMock->method('find')
    ->with($this->equalTo('demo:greet'))
    ->will($this->returnValue($commandMock));
```

You just mock the command and mock the application to return the mocked command.

Comment: I'm mocking another applicaiton, specifically this app here https://github.com/robmorgan/phinx. Under symfony2 component they have an example at the very bottom, 'Calling an Existing Command', this is exactly what I'm doing.

Comment: When I run the code you've provided I get 'The command defined in "Mock_Command_86c6fb40" cannot have an empty name.'. The only difference is on my code, line 2 reads with "...')->with($this->anything())-....", I can see the ->method('run'), that's the method name 'run', so what's the issue?